# Widget (Button Display) Stuck in Bottom Left Corner on UI (Python with Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

**Question:**

How can I keep Widget (Button Display) from getting stuck in bottom left corner of UI?

**Goal:**

I want the button in `WidgetwithButton` to match the format of button in `SomeScreen`. Instead, it is stuck in bottom left corner, barely visible.

Code is provided below.

**Python Code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class WidgetwithButton(Widget):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("buttonformatexample.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**KV Code:**

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:

<WidgetwithButton>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff"
        font_size: 30
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 0.69}
<MainScreen>:
    WidgetwithButton:    
    FloatLayout:    
        Button:
            text: "stuff"
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 0.8}
```

**Output:**

**[image: Output:]**

**Note:**

Bottom left 'stuff' should ideally be same size as above button, and slightly under it (as `pos_hint` code suggests)

Comment: I think you are assuming that a [mcve] refers to your project, in fact a [mcve] refers to a generic code that allows you to reproduce your particular problem, and this should be created by eliminating unnecessary elements that distract such as new types , variables, etc. Your problem is not general, it is dependent on the structure you have designed.

Comment: I've updated the question to display the bare bones problem at hand.

Comment: I do not understand anything.

Comment: I updated the question again with minimal, runnable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WidgetWithButton` is a subclass of `Widget` so it doesn't do anything with  `size_hint` and `pos_hint` (which is for layouts, and each layout uses slightly differently), you might want to make it inherit from `FloatLayout` instead, if you want the same behavior. Alternatively, you could use `pos` and `size` instead of `pos_hint` and `size_hint`.

```
<WidgetwithButton>:
    Button:
        text: "stuff"
        font_size: 30
        # size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
        # the following line will emulate that size_hint without the need of a layout
        size: root.width * 0.25, root.height * 0.1

        # pos_hint: {"x":0, "top": 0.69}
        # the following two lines will emulate the same effect without the need of a layout
        x: root.x
        top: self.height and root.y + root.height * 0.69
```